# Cleaner way than using Type (possibly as?) - code smell looking for cleaner way

Tags: c#, object, types

Dont know what object type will be passed in, if it is type of FishDTO it has a different route to generate the uri, if it is not fish than it is mammal and should follow standard route. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Instead of using type is there a better way using **as**? This works but it just looks ugly:

```
public Uri GetAnimalImageUrl(object animalResult)
{
    if (animalResult.GetType() == typeof(FishDTO))
    {
        return new Uri(GetFishImageUrl((FishDTO)animalResult));
    }

    var mammal = (MammalDTO)animalResult;
    var mammalUrl = GetMammalImageUrl(mammal);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mammalUrl))
    {
        return new Uri(mammalUrl);
    }

    _logger.Error("Image not found for animal");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Make a method that accepts a `FishDTO`.  Make a different method that accepts a `MammalDTO`.  Do those classes have an inheritance relationship?  If so you only need one method...

Answer (score 6):

First off, never do this:

```
    if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Fish))
```

Why not?  Because what if `animal` is a `Goldfish`, a derived type of `Fish`?  `GetType` will return `typeof(Goldfish)`.  Instead, always do this:

```
    if (animal is Fish fish)
```

because that is true regardless of whether `animal` is `Fish` or `Goldfish` or `Shark`.

Second, your code assumes that anything that is not a fish is a mammal, but I think the birds, lizards and crustaceans would like to disagree with you. Your code is not robust in the face of unexpected inputs.

The real question to answer here is *why is the formal parameter of type `object` in the first place*?  That seems like the problem to fix.  If that problem is unfixable, then do your best to fix it:

```
Uri HandleFish(Fish fish) ...
Uri HandleMammal(Mammal mammal) ...
Uri HandleAnimal(Animal animal)
{
  if (x is Fish fish) return HandleFish(fish);
  if (x is Mammal mammal) return HandleMammal(mammal);
  ...
  return HandleOther(x);
}
Uri HandleOther(object x) ...
Uri HandleObject(object x)
{
  if (x is Animal animal) return HandleAnimal(animal);
  ...
  return HandleOther(x);
}
```

Now at least you are working with the type system.

Or, in newer versions of C# you can say

```
switch(x)
{
  case Fish fish: return HandleFish(fish);
  ...
```

An alternative approach is to put the logic in the type hierarchy itself.

```
class Animal
{
  public virtual Uri Handle() ...
}
class Fish : Animal
{
  public override Uri Handle() ...
}
```

And now if `x` is `Animal` then you just `return ((Animal)x).Handle());`

Comment: `if (x is Fish fish) return HandleFish(fish);`

Comment: @UweKeim: Was in the process of making that edit when you commented! I am not in the habit yet of using all the pattern features. :)

Comment: I think a word got omitted from this sentence?  `why is the formal of type object in the first place`.  The formal parameter type?  Not sure.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, "formal" is an adjective.  So it looks to me like a word should go after that.

Comment: @Amy: I, like many compiler writers, am in the habit of referring to formal parameters as "formals".  I'll fix it.

Comment: @Amy: I note that we often do this in other contexts. In Canada the high school dance that Americans call "the prom" is called "the formal", and of course there are many other situations where adjectives are nominalized in English.

Comment: @EricLippert Indeed.  I just didn't know this particular jargon.  Now I do.

Comment: @Amy: The "formal" here is used to disambiguate the *formal parameters* -- that is, the parameters which are *part of the signature of the callee* -- from the *actual parameters* -- the corresponding values which are provided by the caller. Formal parameters and actual parameters are more usually called "parameters" and "arguments" in C#, but I can be old fashioned about these things I suppose. :)

Comment: @EricLippert - just did a minor edit to your code example, hope that was okay.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: Whoops! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Don't forget function overloading; `GetAnimalImageUrl(FishDTO fish)... GetAnimalImageUrl(MammalDTO mammal)`